# RUN PROCEDURE IN MYSQL with two arguments

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a function to calculate the lateral area of a cylinder.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS arealateral$$
CREATE PROCEDURE arealateral(input_number,input_number)
BEGIN
DECLARE raio DECIMAL(10,5);
DECLARE alt DECIMAL (10,5);
SET raio = input_number;
SET alt = input_number;
SELECT 2*pi()*raio*alt;
END$$
DELIMITER;
```

When I run

```
CALL arealateral(1,1)$$
```

the error appear

```
ERROR 1318 (42000): Incorrect number of arguments for PROCEDURE aula3.arealateral; expected 0, got 2
```

Comment: I may be misunderstanding something, but your procedure appears to give both of its parameters the same name (`input_number`). How do your expect to tell the difference between them?

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATED:** Change it to

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS arealateral;

CREATE PROCEDURE arealateral(in raio DECIMAL(10,5), in alt DECIMAL(10,5))
SELECT 2*pi()*raio*alt;
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/023c7/1)**

**UPDATE2:** Based on your subsequent question posted in comments you should utilize [functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html)

```
CREATE FUNCTION arealateral(raio DECIMAL(10,5), alt DECIMAL(10,5))
RETURNS DECIMAL(10,5) DETERMINISTIC
RETURN 2*pi()*raio*alt;

CREATE FUNCTION areatotal(raio DECIMAL(10,5), alt DECIMAL (10,5)) 
RETURNS DECIMAL(10,5) DETERMINISTIC
RETURN 2*areac(raio) + arealateral(raio,alt);
```

Then you can call them like any other function

```
SELECT areatotal(1,1);
SELECT arealateral(1,1);
```

*Don't forget to create `areac` function.*

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/67c05/1)**

Comment: One doesn't even need to use a `BEGIN ... END` compound statement block for a single statement procedure, and therefore also doesn't need to change delimiter: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/50843/1).  Raises the question of whether this should be a procedure at all...

Comment: @SérgioHenrique You're welcome. Glad it helped. Please, consider to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer if it was what you were looking for.

Comment: if I want to calculate the total area using the previous function. DELIMITER $$ DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS areatotal$$ CREATE PROCEDURE areatotal(in raio DECIMAL(10,5), in alt DECIMAL (10,5)) BEGIN SELECT 2*areac(raio) + arealateral(raio,alt); END $$ DELIMITER ; CALL areatotal(1,1)$$ appear ERROR 1305 (42000): FUNCTION aula3.arealateal does not exist

Comment: @SérgioHenrique Your question originally was about procedure not function. And as you learned they are not the same. See updated answer for proper function syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare proc. parameter type as IN, OUT etc. and variable type as VARCHAR(10).
For example,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE arealateral(IN input_number DECIMAL(10,2),IN input_number2 DECIMAL(10,2))
```

Comment: if I want to calculate the total area using the previous function.

`DELIMITER $$`
`DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS areatotal$$`
`CREATE PROCEDURE areatotal(in raio DECIMAL(10,5), in alt DECIMAL (10,5))`
`BEGIN`
`SELECT 2*areac(raio) + arealateral(raio,alt);`
`END $$`
`DELIMITER ;`

`CALL areatotal(1,1)$$`

appear

`ERROR 1305 (42000): FUNCTION aula3.arealateal does not exist`

Comment: Such as CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE. See more details here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html